# Repairing HDD - help to command prompt

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, windows-8.1, repair

I've dropped and destroyed my HDD with family stuff and so on aboard, and I read online, that I should just use `/R /F /X D:` in commandprompt, runned as administrator.

I did that, and this is my cmdprmpt after about 40 hours.

I guess the "ETA" stands for something with "estimated time", or am I wrong?

[Screenshow of Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2QDd.png)

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @gronostaj I hope that the estimate is wrong - it says 65 hours now, and is constantly increasing...

Comment: It's because it hit a sector that's hard to fix. ETA will probably drop when it's fixed. That estimation works quite like in the [copy dialog](http://superuser.com/q/783711/194694).

Comment: As you can see from step four, some bad clusters were detected. This means the disk might not reliable anymore. **Back up any important data you don't want to lose right now**.

Comment: @and31415 Well, it wasn't accessable before, so I'm just crossing everything I have, for this to work.... Otherwise, 7+ years of programming is lost, as well as familymemories (with passed ones too).... :|

Comment: The good news is that the disk checking utility was able to fix the issues detected, or so it seems. Is the process still going, and is there any sign of progress since last time?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your disk is seriously damaged. If it is not your startup disk, why don't you try to recover your files with EASEUS or something of the kind. Older versions of EASEUS are freeware and do the job just as well. Also, your disk is probably physically damaged; in that case, try HDD Regenator, it fixes damaged sectors regardless of the OS used.

Answer (score 0):

Great, after lots and lots of patience, it suddenly was all done. Almost all of the files wasn't working probably, so I ran `chkdsk d: /f /r` and while writing, I'm compromising all of the files to a RAR that will be uploaded to a cloudservice.

I thank you for all of your help :).

Answer (score 0):

@
Back up any important data you don't want to lose right now.
Take doc and photos not a hole directory. If the drive or controller card get stuck. It can be hard to see what was completed in the backup. You can end up have a broken file.
If you don't trust the computer make a backup on another one. If it calculates wrong it, chkdsk will also read the info wrong and damage the filesystem.
WD Green hade a problem many many Y ago. the controler culd try in ca 2min. The disk did time out during the time. OS.